# Making Pascal's triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def tri(fib_lst,n):

    lst = []
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(n):
            if i == 0 or i == n-1:
                lst.append(1)
            else:
                lst.append((i-1)+i)
    if n <= 1:
        lst.append(1)
    return lst

def draw_pascal_triangle(fib_lst,n):

    for i in range(n):
        fib_lst.append(tri(fib_lst, i+1))
```

Then to get results I entered the following:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst2 = []
>>> draw_pascal_triangle(lst, 5)
>>> draw_pascal_triangle(lst, 8)
>>> print(lst)
>>> print(lst2)
```

The results were:

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 3, 5, 1], [1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 3, 5, 1], [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1], [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1], [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 1]]
```

I know that my problem is occurring in the line:

```
else:
    lst.append((i+1)+i)
```

but I don't know what to do to fix my mistake.

Comment: Did you mean to pass the same list to both function calls?

Comment: yes i did!! well to get my last results i needed to run both function calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code, I just changed one line of what you wrote:

```
def tri(fib_lst,n):
    lst = []
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(n):
            if i == 0 or i == n-1:
                lst.append(1)
            else:
                lst.append(fib_lst[-1][i-1]+fib_lst[-1][i])
    if n <= 1:
        lst.append(1)
    return lst

def draw_pascal_triangle(fib_lst,n):
    for i in range(n):
        fib_lst.append(tri(fib_lst, i+1))
```

Then:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst2 = []
>>> draw_pascal_triangle(lst, 5)
>>> draw_pascal_triangle(lst, 8)
>>> print('\n'.join([str(l) for l in lst]))
>>> print('\n'.join([str(l) for l in ls2]))
```

Result:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]

[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
```

Your mistake was an algorithmic mistake. Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

We have `lst[n][k] = lst[n-1][k-1] + lst[n-1][k]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple pascal generator I just made.

```
def generatePascal(depth):        
    pascal = [[1]]

    for level in range(depth):
        lastRow = pascal[-1]
        paddedLastRow = [0] + lastRow + [0]
        nextRow = []
        for position in range(len(paddedLastRow) - 1):
            nextRow.append(paddedLastRow[position] + paddedLastRow[position+1])
        pascal.append(nextRow)

    return pascal
```

For example:

```
>>> generatePascal(4)
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```